# Athena queries between tables in different accounts

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I can individually access two different Athena tables using two different IAM roles because each lie in different accounts.

Is there a way to run a single query that pulls from both (ie. INNER JOIN)?

Comment: Hey @aidan.plenert.macdonald did u get an answer?

Comment: @AadityaChauhan Unfortunately, at this point, it can't be done with IAM roles because you can't assume two roles together and get the superset of privileges. But a coworker claims he succeeded in doing this by using a bucket policy that opens to the different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, *Athena table data is in S3 bucket*.

Athena supports cross-account S3 bucket access.

Assume you've Account A & B and Athena table TableA and TableB respectively.

Steps to run query from AccountA Athena (access cross-account data):

1. Provide AccountA IAM Role read access on AccountB S3 bucket Policy
   (where TableB data resides).
2. Create TableB in AccountA Athena, referring to S3 bucket data in
   AccountB.
3. Use TableA & and TableB in AccountA and do Inner join

Ref (cross-account access): https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/