# Can an RDS Instance Assume a role from another account?

Tags: amazon-iam, rds, amazon-aurora, assume-role

I am trying to load S3 data from Account A Bucket into an RDS instance in account B. I cannot use Resource policy. It needs to be done only using IAM roles.

I have a Role Created in Account A and it has access to the S3 Bucket.
I have a Role Create in Account B which allows Assume Role from Account A.

How do I use these to load Data from Account A to Account B?

Comment: What if you give the role in account B permission to access the bucket, in both a policy attached to the role, and in the bucket policy?  Wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom loader because you need to assume 2 roles at the same time.

One way would be to create 2 programs that pipe the data.

```
$ read_bucket | write_rds
```

The read_bucket script would assume the Account A role and read the contents from the bucket.  It would then print the data to stdout.

The write_rds script would assume the Account B role and read the contents from stdin and then write to RDS.

You can do this all inside on program because when you assume a role you get back a set of temporary credentials that you include with each API request.  Here is another [answer specifically on temporary credentials.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876077/assume-multiple-aws-iam-roles-are-a-single-time)